# Clean up Browser Cache

Tags: java, jsp, caching

I´m programming Java App. and get an error, because browser don't connect to server to take new values, just renderize from cache...
I make something like this:

```
<% if(request.getAttribute("msg")!=null)
    out.println("alert("+request.getAttribute("msg")+")");
%>
```

It works fine, but when i click on a link and then click on BACK button from browser it dont call server... I tried something like: `response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-Cache");` on Java
and `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="no-cache">` on html, but nothing make it work...
anyone have a suggest?

Comment: I am not sure why you used the `javascript` tag, but this is **definitely** not JavaScript. You're exposing a JSP *scriptlet* which is printing a JS alert (*scriptlets* should by the way be [avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) as much as possible). So I replaced the `javascript` tag by `jsp` one.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your browser is set to request new pages every time you visit a site. You may also want to add a extra parameter to request like a time stamp so that it always looks like a new request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to instruct the webbrowser to not cache the response by setting the appropriate response headers. The correct set of response headers are those:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

You'd like to do this in a `Filter` class which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of interest, e.g. `*.jsp` rather than copypasting the same over all JSP pages.

#### See also:

- [Making sure a webpage is not cached, across all rowsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)
- [Caching tutorial for webmasters and webdevelopers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)

PS: don't forget to clear the browser cache before testing, the old page might be still in there ;)